# how to remove the html content in vue2editor

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

We a create a html content using Vue Editor and save the data and close the dialog after saving . how do we remove the html content in the editor after the dialog box is closed

Using this editor for writing a html document in Vuejs --

import { VueEditor } from 'vue2-editor'

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to reset data property which has been passed to "v-model" attribute, something like that:

```
<template>
  <vue-editor v-model="content" />
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      content: '<p>Sample</p>',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    save() {
      // Closing dialog code
      this.content = null; // or this.content = ''
    },
  },
};
</script>
```